# Why can you use "a" for "This/That" --> "That is an excellent book"

Tags: articles

I have been going over this website - 
http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm

It gives the example sentence:

"That is an excellent book."

I am a native speaker so I know this sounds natural, but why isn't "the" appropriate here?

According to this flow chart, it seems "the" should be used since the book is known to the reader (at least I think it is!).

http://www.gallaudet.edu/tip/english-center/grammar-and-vocabulary/when-to-use-a-an-or-the.html

Comment: Quite the contrary, unless someone wants to explicitly refer to something as important, or an unfamiliar/unknown quality, then the is not warranted. There's a very large amount of books possessed by humanity, and the specific sentence points to a concrete book, which is a known quality for the one who says that sentence. Not to mention "the excellent" and "an excellent" book means two different things: One is excellency in book form(edit from bookiest book), and the other one is just excellent. Sounds nuanced, but in context, it means everything.

Comment: Thanks! If someone says "This", wouldn't I know which book they are talking about? I know that those 2 sentences are very different. I am just confused about how, in this case, the book is not known.

Answer (score 3):

Your chart says this:

> Use "a" or "an" with a singular count noun when you mean **"one of
>   many,"** "any," "in general."

*Book* is such a noun, and the sentence

> This is **an** excellent book.

means that among the **many** books available, this **one** is excellent.

The chart continues:

> Use "the" with any noun when the meaning is specific; for example,
>   when the noun names the only one (or one) of a kind.

So the definite article would be appropriate to identify a book unique to the conversation:

> This is **the** excellent book I told you about yesterday.